# Finding users who liked a post

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, active-record

I have a method `liked_by` and it doesn't seem like appropriate as per Ruby style. I need to do it as less as possible.

```
  def liked_by
    if !object.likes.nil?
      like = Like.where(bonus_id: bonus.id)
      users = []
      like.each do |likes|
        liked_user = User.find_by(id: likes.user_id)
        users.push(liked_user.email)
      end
    end
    return users
  end
```

The main logic is:

1. I check if any likes to post available (`likes.nil?`)
2. I create users array (`users = []`)
3. For each like, I find a user with `like.user_id` and push this user to the `users` array

In the end, I return `users`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use joined tables to make more performant database calculations and avoid unnecessary models instantiations.

```
def liked_by
  return [] unless object.likes.present?
  User.distinct.joins(:likes).where(likes: { bonus_id: bonus.id }).pluck(:email)
end
```